# Separate or Single Root Module in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have two pages:

1. Index.html (Home Page)
2. Admin.html (Admin Control Panel with Sign-in mandatory to access this page)

for these pages, do I need to create separate root module or single root module?
And how to bundle them in case there is single root module using webpack.

Comment: It looks like 2 different websites. you can put the folders next to each other but have them link to common resources. they will have separate bootstrap module.

Comment: @HaddarMacdasi -  I have single website under which I have two different pages. In this, do I need common bootstrap module or separate bootstrap module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are 2 different html, each html file will include the js scripts it needs in order to init.
I will have 2 different bundles of js so I can update user interface only or admin only and not connect the scripts between them. You could have same common module imported for each AppModule and AdminAppModule, I think there will be some common functionality and common components they both would use.
One more thing to think about is the server should be able to serve the index.html as well as the admin.html. so you can navigate to yoursie.com/index and yoursite.com/admin.

Comment: Thank for your help.... Probably there is no way in Angular 2 where we can get the running instance of angular app like

`var app = angular.module("yourApp");`

And dynamically injecting modules

`app.requires.push("ThirdPartyModule");`